# PHP image upload WITHOUT losing EXIF data

Tags: php, ios, exif, imagecreatefrompng

Really struggling to find a way around this...

Uploading images taken in portrait on an iPhone are rotated because of their EXIF orientation.

I have tried to retrieve this data but it gets stripped when using:

```
imagecreatefromstring();
```

I am looking for the correct way / a way to upload an image without removing the EXIF data.

Currently it is this:

```
$imagefile = $fileToUpload["tmp_name"];
$destinationImage = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($imagefile));
$exif = exif_read_data($imagefile);
$moveUploadedFile = imagejpeg($destinationImage, $this->uploadDir . "/" . $newFileName, 100);
imagedestroy($destinationImage);

if ($moveUploadedFile) {
  $return['ort'] = $exif;
  echo json_encode($return);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: just move the uploaded file, dont create a new one

Comment: The EXIF data is still removed after doing this:  $imagefile = $fileToUpload["tmp_name"];
        $exif = exif_read_data($imagefile);
        $moveUploadedFile = move_uploaded_file($fileToUpload["tmp_name"], $this->uploadDir . "/" . $newFileName);

Comment: moving a file does not change it s contents

Comment: Where is the code that does the actual reading of EXIF data? How can you prove that the EXIF data gets removed?

Comment: When i return the $exif variable as json. I have also downloaded the image after its uploaded and checked it using an iphone app and the data is removed.